# Can I get Claptastic Voyage for The Handsome Collection on the ps4?

Tags: ps4, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I bought the disc but can't locate any DLC for claptastic voyage. Is it not available on the ps4?

Comment: What do you mean you can't locate it? You can't get the DLC to start or you can't see it as an available DLC to download?

Comment: I can't find it to download in the playstation store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claptastic Voyage should be included with the Handsome Collection.

Simply take the Quick Travel system to Deck 13 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

The downloadable content “Claptastic Voyage” is included with purchase of Borderlands: The Handsome Collection, but is not on the physical disc. It will need to be downloaded from PlayStation Network / Xbox LIVE. You will need to make sure you have the latest update for Borderlands: The Handsome Collection. - gearbox swoftware

Source : [Post on Gearbox Software Zendesk](https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205281250-Claptastic-Voyage-DLC-Not-Available-in-Borderlands-The-Pre-Sequel)

Comment: Do you have a source? This conflicts with the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is not correct (at least for the ps4 version). I did not realize when I asked the question that there was a Quick Travel to Deck 13 1/2 (I remember feeling silly for playing through the whole game twice and never noticing it)